# Mapping that has no fixed point on subset of $l_{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider $l_{\infty}=\lbrace x=(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}: x_{n} \in \mathbb{R} \, \, \text{for all} \,\, n \in \mathbb{N} \,\, \text{and} \,\, sup\, _{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x_n| < \infty \rbrace$. Now, let $X \subset l_{\infty} $ defined by $X = \lbrace (\xi_{i}) \in \bar{B}(0,1), \exists \, k \,\, \text{with} \,\, \xi_{i} = 0 \, \forall \, i \geq k \rbrace$, where $\bar{B}(0,1) = \lbrace x \in l_{\infty}, ||x||_{\infty} \leq 1 \rbrace$. Give an example of a mapping $T:X \rightarrow X $ such that $d(Tx,Ty)<d(x,y)$ for all $x\neq y$ but $T$ has no fixed point.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: No, I am going to do a test so I downloaded some tests on the subject to answer but I can't find the solution to this problem.

Comment: Normally in the context of Banach spaces the term "operator" refers to a *linear* operator. Clearly, every linear operator has a fixed point, namely, zero. Therefore, I would emphasise that what you are looking for is a general mapping, not an "operator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us define a $T: X \to X$ by the following rule of assignment: let $x \in X$, then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the $(n+1)$-th term of $T(x)$ is given by $\frac{x_n}{2}$, and the first term of $T(x)$ is 1.  That is:
$$
x \mapsto \bigg(1, \frac{x_1}{2}, \frac{x_2}{2}, \ldots \bigg).
$$
Note that for all $x,y \in X$,
$$
\|T(x) - T(y) \| < \gamma \|x-y\|
$$
for any $\gamma \in (.5,1)$, and $T$ is fixed-point free as for any $x \in X \setminus \{0\}$ there is a well-defined minimal $k\in \mathbb{N}$ at which point the sequence $x$ is forever after zero, but this value is always one greater for $T(x)$.  Thus the only fixed point could be zero, but clearly $T(0) \neq 0$ .